# disable day selection in datepicker

Tags: javascript, html

any idea how to disable day selection in date picker and restrict it only to month ?

```html
<input type="date" value="2018-07-22" min="2018-01-01" max="2018-12-01">
```

I have this small spa where the body takes alost half of the page

Comment: bootstrap datapicker or normal datapicker ?

Comment: normal datepicker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input type `month` instead of `date`

```html
<label for="start">Start month:</label>

<input type="month" id="start" name="start"
       min="2018-01" max="2018-12" value="2018-07">
```

Comment: can it be numerical ?

Comment: I don't think so. At least not using the default HTML5 tags.

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if this suits you?